# Delete specific lines in a string in Google Sheets using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wanted a Google sheet Script to delete certain lines in a string that contains specific text and also delete the line break that corresponds to it.

I was able to do this with regexreplace but it isn't ideal if you have large amounts of data. So the idea is to remove the entire line in the string with the word "apple" and its corresponding line break and also delete all line breaks at the end after the last line of text.

This is an example of what I wanted to achieve.

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iup1v.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please set the sheet name.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const word = "apple"; // This is from your question.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const re = new RegExp(`^.*${word}.*\\n?`, "gmi");
  const values = range.getValues().map(r => r.map(c => c.replace(re, "").trim()));
  range.offset(0, 2).setValues(values);
}
```

- If you want to use the script as a custom function, please use the following script. In this case, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE("A2:A")` into a cell.

  ```js
  function SAMPLE(values) {
    const word = "apple"; // This is from your question.

    const re = new RegExp(`^.*${word}.*\\n?`, "gmi");
    return values.map(r => r.map(c => c.replace(re, "").trim()));
  }
  ```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained. The cells "C2" and "D" are from the 1st and the 2nd script, respectively.

[image]

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: @Zee About `Hi Tanaike! This worked perfectly. Thank you so much!`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer